# Javascript chart component that can handle annotated news headlines

Tags: javascript, charts, raphael, highcharts

I am looking for a Javascript chart component that can embed news headlines directly on the chart, similar to what is available with [Google Finance](http://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3aXOM)

I know that this is possible in Flash with e.g. Google Chart Tools (http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html) or amCharts (http://amcharts.com/stock/events/), but I'd prefer to avoid using Flash, because of use with iPad and iPhone.

I have also been looking at Flot (http://code.google.com/p/flot/) and Humble (http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/index), but since these are made using the canvas element, I don't think they work well enough in IE. I know they both use excanvas to make it possible to use them in IE, but they just don't perform well enough. I have been testing them in IE 6-9 on several computers and the results simply aren't good enough for me to confident in using them.

I have been quite impressed with Highcharts (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/?example=line-time-series&theme=default) and Raphael (http://g.raphaeljs.com/), but neither of those have implemented annotated news headlines by default, so it would require a lot of work to get it done. Do you have any other suggestions on how to do this without flash and without using canvas?

Also I would be happy to see demos, if anyone has implemented a similar solution.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

One of the examples for Raphael (the original graphics library, not the graphs extension linked to in the question) looks like it may be close to what you are looking for: http://raphaeljs.com/analytics.html

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but if somebody still finds it - you can have this with JavaScript version of amCharts: http://www.amcharts.com/stock-chart/stock-events/

Disclaimer: I am the author of amCharts.